# Ubuntu 12.04 cannot boot after running update to 3.2.0-97

Tags: 12.04, boot, updates

I ran updates from the update manager today on my ASUS notebook and when it asked for reboot, it hung at the splash screen.  Every time I try to reboot, it hangs at the splash screen.

I tried running recovery mode from GRUB boot but that did not help, I get a repeating message:

```
udevd [360] timeout killing /sbn/modprobe -bv pci: longstringnumbers [597]
```

I can boot into previous version 3.2.0-92 from GRUB.

Is there a way to delete this update and revert to previous?  Or should I consider saving my data and restore to factory?

Answer (score 1):

if something doesn't work as expected after you updated your kernel (or to be more specific: something hardware related no more works as it was working before), the easiest method is to simply **uninstall the new kernel**:

- first restart your computer (`sudo shutdown -r now`)
- at the beginning of the reboot (even before the splash-screen) hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-key
- now you are in the GRUB-menu and it should look something like this:

  ```
  Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-97-generic
  Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-97-generic (recovery mode)
  Previous Linux versions
  Memory Test (memtest86+)
  Memory Test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
  ```
- use the arrow keys to choose `Previous Linux versions`, and then your previous working kernel like `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-92-generic` (or whatever kernel-version it was).
- after your system has booted (and everything is working as before the update) open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.2.0-97* linux-image-3.2.0-97*` (make sure you have entered the correct version-number twice).

and that's it... GRUB should be updated automatically and you can try to restart your system and everything should be working as it was!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to delete this update and revert to previous?  YES.

Steps:

1. Please prepare a live USB and then plugin it to your notebook. Boot with the live USB.
2. Get ready to use the live Desktop environment
3. mount your laptop disk by nautilus
4. open the terminal(<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>)
5. apply this command `sudo chroot /media/<your account name>/<a_UUID_or_something_like that_indicates_your_hard_disk_you_just_mounted>`
6. now you are in your laptop root filesystem. use the command
   `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-the_kernel_could_not_boot_successfully` to remove the malfunction kernel.
7. exit the chroot by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>
8. reboot the system.
9. in the grub menu you should not see the grub entry for the bad kernel if you remove it successfully.

Comment: it is not recommended to manually delete kernels! - moreover it is more work (creating & using a live-medium), somehow complicated and potentially dangerous.