# Ubuntu server is unable to boot after update

Tags: boot, server

[this is what I get when I'm trying to boot it up. Any help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IIXe.jpg)

Comment: boot an old kernel

Comment: Well, I'm unable to do anything. How should I proceed? Push some button to access Grub or boot from a USB stick?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

Comment: I managed to find that before you answered and also booted into an older kernel without any issues. Is there anything else I should do to prevent that in the future?

Comment: file a bug report against the new kernel.

Comment: After removing use this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764241/how-to-remove-new-kernel-and-make-older-default-16-04  to remove that faulty kernel

Comment: There is a 3.2.0-126 kernel (and maybe even more recent than that, I don't know). Suggest you try it, as maybe your issue with 3.2.0-121 has been fixed.

Comment: Most likely the latest kernel upgrade didn't finish. A good solution would be to re-install the latest kernel, or running `sudo apt full upgrade` from the working kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your system/server  starts to boot press <kbd>C</kbd> key. In this mode,select a different kernel and try to boot in it.

If it fails then you need to first backup everthing using a live linux distro.

Now as its a kernel panic you would need to first mount the partiton in live mode. In this case I first suggest you to install new kernel and update the grub

Step 1:  Boot using a live CD/USB

Step 2:  type command `df -h` and obtain the partition where Ubuntu is     installed

Step 3 : Mount the partiton where ubuntu is using the Command `sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt` where `X` matches the partition title.

Step 4 : Now its time to get new kernels so either download it before hand or you may do it now.

Goto [ubuntu kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com), select the latest kernel. In my case its `v4.14-rc1`, so click that. Now based on your server arch you can download the kernels.
To know the arch,type the command `uname -a` to get a fair knowledge of the kernel arch. X86 shows its 32 bits, x86_64 shows its a 64 bits processor with support for 32. So I would download  these in case of 64 bits

- linux-headers-4.14.0-041400rc1_4.14.0-041400rc1.201709162031_all.deb
- linux-headers-4.14.0-041400rc1-generic_4.14.0-041400rc1.201709162031_amd64.deb
- linux-image-4.14.0-041400rc1-generic_4.14.0-041400rc1.201709162031_amd64.deb

You can do these either by making a text file (I would call it as kernel.list)  having all the links, saving that and then using wget to download these all. 
In your case it should be

```
sudo wget -i /dev/sdx/kernel.list
```

Then type

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdX
```

This will install all the kernel file at `/dev/sdx` to its mounted volume at `/mnt`. or you could simply do the `wget -i kernel.list` on another machine. Copy paste it to `/dev/sdx` using the command `

```
sudo cp /usb_driver /dev/sdx
```

and then install kernel by

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdX
```

Step 5: Now in terminal type

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdX
```

these will re-install `grub2`.

Step 6: Now simply reboot , command "sudo reboot"  and check wheter it works or not.

Note :

- Step 5 installs new kernel
- Step 6 re installs grub2 so that your bootloader is fixed and is linked with your new kernel.

Comment: thanks George for helping me out by formatting my post/answer.

Comment: Why do you think installing a RC kernel is a good solution?

Comment: Though rc aka release candidate can be thought as an unstable kernel. Its usually not due to agile/scrum nature of Linux Kernel. Now a new kernel brings lots of security feature,new updates and new drivers for sure.        If you are still not satisfied you may consider a stable/generic kernel yourself , but I have my own experiences stating that If one knows what he/she is doing,then he/she can fix it.

Comment: Example : Previously I used Ubuntu Trusty , which was working fine. All of a sudden my audio stoped woking and it left my system audio less. I had then re installed/purge/install alsa,alsa-base,pulseaudio,pavucontrol lots of times. It still didnt get fixed. So instead I simply upgraded to the newest kernel ,ubuntu had and re installed all the audio packages once more and lo audio was back.

Comment: Following your recommendation, I booted an old kernel and chose the "easy" option of doing a dist upgrade (it needed one anyway). It upgraded itself to 14.04 with a 3.13.0-129 kernel which obviously fixed the problem. Anyway I'll be reinstalling that server as it's been causing me a few problems lately.

And thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am relieved my self as the first option did the work. else fixing would had required lots of installation which is not feasible in server enviroment. However I would suggest you to create containers/hypervisor  as upgrading would be far easier , you could deploy a lots of them  and even mount/start one if one of them fails.