# Screen resolution issues after latest system update on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: xorg, xrandr

After the latest 17.04 system update my laptop only works in 1024x768 mode and doesn't allow me to choose any other resolution. With the latest system update I got the 4.10.0.37 kernel plus some X11 modifications. I guess the latest one screwed up something in my config. I'm using an Asus UL20A with integrated Intel GPU and I used the latest Intel drivers.

When I'm trying to run xrnadr it's giving me the below message:

```
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

Does anyone has any idea where should I start the investigation? If I need to provide any log dump please let me know what exactly that should be.

Here are the display related information provided by lshw command:

```
*-display:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe400000-fe7fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:cc00(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe800000-fe8fffff
```

Comment: This is a no so newer graphics driver... Does it have a GMA 4500MHD? Could you append `sudo lshw -C video`output into your question?

Comment: @Redbob Yes, it has a Embedded Intel GMA 4500MHD. The above option doesn't print me anything to the screen. It just lists the help. I tried to run it with other options to generate a html output but I don't know where does it put the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the new kernel screwed up my setup, so I reverted back to the previous kernel (4.10.0-35). [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764241/how-to-remove-new-kernel-and-make-older-default-16-04) helped me how to revert back to the previous kernel. So, what I did was I removed the latest linux headers and image by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.10.0-37*
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.10.0-37*
```

Comment: Issue already reported on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1296020